# Eclipse+GCC for FORTRAN : program make not found in PATh

Tags: eclipse, gcc, path, fortran, mingw

I am a total newbie to `eclipse` and `minGW` compiler and I am facing a problem when bulding a project:

Firstly I was obtaining the error `gcc` not found in PATh. Then I added the `bin` folders of `minGW` to PATh variables both on windows settings and in the path list under

```
project options->build->environment
```

Now I get a similar error saying that make is not found but `make.exe` is in the same folder that `gcc` that as I mentioned is already in PATh. Both `make.exe` (is a copy of `mingw32-make.exe`) and `mingw32-make.exe` are indeed in the folder.

When running in the `cmd`:

> C:\Users\Liliana>gcc.exe gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
>   compilation terminated.
>
> C:\Users\Liliana>make.exe make.exe: *** No targets specified and no
>   makefile found.  Stop.
>
> C:\Users\Liliana>mingw32-make.exe mingw32-make.exe: *** No targets
>   specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Any hint on why is `gcc.exe` being understood to be in PATH but not `make.exe`? I already tried everything I saw on similar questions here..
Many thanks!

Comment: The way I see it `make.exe` _is_ being found.  It's make that's complaining about the lack of a makefile.

Comment: And how do I get such makefile?

Comment: The makefile is indeed in the project folder within eclipse